# Jmeter null url detected (should not happen)

Tags: jmeter

My jmeter log indicates me alot of same kind of warnings which makes me clueless

```
WARN - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Null URL detected (should not happen)
```

what should i look for? i ve googled around but cant find any info related to my issue.
Add: The Test at all is running fine.

Comment: In http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.java.html see where is throw exception.

Comment: it has with httpClient4 - to do 4.1?? do i get as response something wrong from backend? or do i send something wrong as request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you check download resources.
The message is issued when one of the URLs returned by the HTML Page parser is null.

This is not supposed to happen, if it does it seems to be a bug:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55092

As per your bug report, it happens because you have iframe tags which source is:

- about:blank

Bug will be fixed in 2.10 version of JMeter

As a workaround you can uncheck download resources, you test will then work only on dynamic resources, not static ones (images,css,js ...)

Comment: Would be nice to open a bug with a page